# BUG ? Can't reference cell from formula where sheet name contains a comma

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference

Even the built-in reference generation in Excel fails at this. In a blank worksheet, type in cell A1:
`=vlookup(A2,`
then switch to a sheet with a comma in its name and choose a cell range using the mouse. Then append:
`,1)`
and hit enter. You should have something like this in A1:

`=VLOOKUP(A2,'CL 01 Crane, IN'!D6:D27,1)`

Now, if you edit the formula and click after the first comma, the function help will show that the argument you're looking at is named `table_array`, which is correct (arg 2). But now click after the comma in the sheet name for the vlookup table reference, and you'll see that the comma has been taken as the vlookup argument separator, rather than kept as part of the sheet name. With the cursor at this location, the function help should still say `table_array` (arg 2), but it says `col_index_num`, which is the next argument (arg 3).

Remember that we had Excel itself create this reference by using the mouse to select the table range. The structure of the generated reference seems correct to me; the formula parser just seems to be confused.

Tom

Comment: Maybe a bug but you can definitely still write a functioning VLOOKUP so I fail to see the point of the question.

Comment: I also don't see a question here (other than maybe asking for confirmation)? I can confirm that the function works but the helper doesn't, which may not be a huge priority for the testers. In any case just report it to Microsoft through Excel Support (you can use the Help function within the app to contact support)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question but a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like you're right, and the problem cascades with multiple commas in the sheet name.

One workaround if this causes the parser to become too difficult to use is to place the reference to the other sheet in brackets (). Using the example formula it would look like this: `=VLOOKUP(A2,('CL 01 Crane, IN'!D6:D27),1)`, which forces the parser to recognize this as a reference and not two parts to a formula.

This is a fun one, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thank you for understanding my implied question of "has anyone else seen this" and "what's a clean way to work around it". Your method is clean and simple and in my testing, addressed the issue. Plus I learned something new! Thanks.